# Eliminate line sections in a merge to use Qchainage plug in

Tags: merge, road, qchainage

in QGis I merged several layers, each containing sections of a road, to show a longer route on a map. Now when I want to use the qchainage plug in the plug in starts the count over again in each 'section' of the road before i merged them. How can I 'smooth' the route so that the plug in sees it as a single road?

Answer (score 0):

When you use "Merge vector layer" you are just reuniting the line from each different layer into the same layer but each line remain a separate object.

To merge all the line together you need to run the "Merge lines" tool on your merged layer. (to ensure best result made sure that your line are effectively connected by their extremities, also as I don't know how the merge line and qchainage react to opposite oriented line if you still enconter problems you may want to check that your line are digitized in the same orientation ie. that the last vertice of the first line is connected to the first vertice of the second line and so on)